# How can I bulk rename files in a photo folder with sequential numbers

Tags: php, file, rename, bulk

**This was a poorly worded question**

My main goal was to display many images or even a range from a set arbitrarily, renaming the files to sequential numbers seemed like it would make the displaying or iterating through the files easier if they just differed by 1 rather than random strings.

-- anyway I'm going to read... seems glob is according to php manual ... **The glob() function searches for all the pathnames matching pattern according to the rules used by the libc glob() function**

The files have random names but they are all .jpg's

As an example,  "this name".jpg is replaced with "i+1".jpg

So that I can display the photos lazily using a for loop incrementing the numbers. The primary purpose is to display the photos regardless of their file names.

Comment: Have you tried anything to do this?

Comment: No I have never attempted this before, I have researched briefly and it is not a huge priority at the moment. I have seen some methods but the one example involved "SKU's" eg. taking a specific string out.

Comment: @janicehoplin Maybe it's interesting for you to read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3933332

Comment: why increment numbers, why not just get the files in the directory and loop through them, that way you won't get a file not found if a file is deleted.

Comment: The [tag:processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Comment: @Pete, there was no particular reason for renaming them... yes I would have and perhaps should have directly used the file names, I have not implemented or tried anything like this before. And when looping I've only used the i++ incrementer not varying string combinations/length

Comment: @Kevin Workman, I used the tag as I have seen the term "batch processing" before...which may not be relevant to this at all so... what the hell right? I don't know

Comment: If you just need to do it once, theres a tool here that will allow you to rename, renumber, modify filenames in a a variety of ways.   https://pacificblue.software/file?name=file_smith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php [glob](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.glob.php) and [rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) functions:

```
$num = 1;
foreach (glob("/path/to/images/*.jpg") as $filename) {
    $fileNoExtension = basename($filename, ".jpg");
    rename ($filename, "$fileNoExtension{$num}.jpg");
    $num++;
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75895/discussion-between-janicehoplin-and-pedro-lobito).

Comment: I don't really know what to do, I keep trying to launch businesses but they are out of my reach financially and they may be stupid or have some inherent flaw. I guess what I'm after is sanity or vindication through financial success or happiness.

Comment: hmm I guess a "moderator" removed my comments, would be nice if they told you and didn't just hide under their "powers" it's just data these "plus 1's" maybe they didn't disappear. Time will tell.

Answer (score 1):

Basically,

```
$count = 1;
foreach (glob('*.jpg') as $filename) {
  @rename($filename, $count.'.jpg');
  $count++;
}

echo 'Done';
```

All image files must be in the current folder (along with the script).

You can add a path manually, if you wish:

```
 glob('/path/to/*.jpg')
 rename('path/..'.$file etc. )
```

Comment: thanks Alex M, I'll have to implement this and see how it goes, my brain is demolished at the moment, I haven't attempted batch "anything" before especially dealing with dynamic content eg. doesn't follow a pattern

Comment: @alex on the `@rename` change from `$file` to `$filename`.